# Segmentation fault in Stack Pop function for tree in C language

Tags: c, data-structures

I am using this function in a tree program on Codeblocks it is showing there segmentation fault in Pop function where i am freeing the Tree node.Segmentation fault is like Program Received Signal SIGSEGV segmentation, i understood this error comes out due to `isEmptyStack()` is not getting return ever 1(only 0) value.It seems that there is error in Pop function, I need help in this regard, I am stuck here from many days plz help me out.

// Stack Implementation for Tree type node

```
typedef struct TreeStructure
{
    int data;
    struct TreeStructure *left;
    struct TreeStructure *right;
}Tree;

typedef struct SListNode
{
    struct TreeStructure *data;
    struct ListNode *next;
}SList;

typedef struct StackList
{
    struct ListNode *Node;
}Stack;

Stack *CreationStack()
{
    return NULL;
}

int isEmptyStack(Stack *top)
{
    return top==NULL;
}
void Push(Stack **top,Tree *data)
{
    SList *new,*tmp;
    new=malloc(sizeof *new);  // Modification here according to comments
    new->data=data;
    new->next=*top;
        *top=new;
}

Tree *Pop(Stack **top)
{   
    Tree *data;
    SList *tmp;
    if(isEmptyStack(*top))
    {
        printf("Underflow") ;return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        tmp=*top;
        *top=tmp->next;
        data=tmp->data;
        if(tmp)            // using do not let occur case of the dangling pointer
            free(tmp);        // Showing fault here only on Debugging
        return data;
    }
}
```

This is For Preserve order printing of a level order Tree.... Left to Right and Bottom to up,

```
 #include<stdlib.h>
 typedef struct TreeStructure
 {
     int data;
     struct TreeStructure *left;
     struct TreeStructure *right;
 }Tree;
 typedef struct ListQueue
 {
     struct ListNode *Rear;
     struct ListNode *Front;
 }Queue;

typedef struct ListNode
{
    struct TreeStructure *node;
    struct Listnode *next;
}List;

typedef struct SListNode
{
    struct TreeStructure *data;
    struct ListNode *next;

}SList;

typedef struct StackList
{
    struct ListNode *Node;
}Stack;

void Reverseorder(Tree *Root)
{
     Stack *top; Queue *Q;
     Tree *tmp;
     if(!Root)
         return ;
     top=CreationStack();
     Q=Creation();
     Enqueue(Q,Root);

     while(!isEmpty(Q))
     {

         tmp=Dequeue(Q);
         Push(&top,tmp);
         if(tmp->right)
             Enqueue(Q,tmp->right);
         if(tmp->left)
             Enqueue(Q,tmp->left);
     }


     while(!isEmptyStack(top))     // Here Empty checker is going into infinite loop 
                                   // due to this error occurs
         printf("\nReverse Element is %d",Pop(&top)->data);

 }
```

As I have checked other functions are working right, whenever I tried to augment my code a bit more, from there problem start coming, plz do not confuse about other functions

Comment: Please, don't cast malloc. If you recieve warnings when using malloc without casts, ask us about them. Otherwise, use a C compiler to compile C code, instead of a C++ compiler.

Comment: Additionally, masking pointers behind typedefs results in extremely confusing code for others to read. When you see `int`, do you expect `int *`? No. Why not write code to be consistent with the rest of the C programming language?

Comment: I can see that this question hasn't had any answers yet... Let us know when you've made it appear as though you want us to *read* the code, rather than moving on to the next question because *it's unreadable*.

Comment: I have removed masked pointers... in a hope to get answerd.

Comment: Note that your malloc cast is now a compiler error: `new=(SList)malloc(sizeof(struct SListNode));`... Perhaps you meant `new = malloc(sizeof *new);`.

Comment: modifiable lvalue... Sir result persists as it is and even the same place.

Comment: I believe you've misdiagnosed. If you had formed a [short, self contained, correct (compilable) example](http://sscce.org/), I might be inclined to believe otherwise. However, your code doesn't compile, and I see that as the most significant problem at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Please review your code yourself carefully before posting it here. Here is a thing that I caught at a first glance, there are most likely others, since you simply don't have applied enough care to get things correct.

Your function `Push`:

- has an unused variable `tmp`
- a bogus call to `malloc`
- uses `typedef`ed pointers
- distinguishes two cases but which then are exactly equivalent

Comment: I found your reply useful but still things are not working... can you help me further. I appreciate your reply

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `data` is a dangling pointer inside the pop function. When you free tmp, you also free the TreeStructure pointed by data.

Comment: Sir bcz the program data is Tree Node that's why I am returning Tree type data rather than deleting it.